# Svelte navigator: use multiple query parameters

Tags: svelte

I'm using `svelte-navigator` and I have this component (`App`):

```
<main>
  <Router primary={false}>
    <Route path={'/'}>
      <Homepage />
    </Route>
    <Route path={'/something'}>
      Something
    </Route>
    <Route>
      <h3>Default</h3>
    </Route>
  </Router>
</main>
```

So, basically 3 routes: homepage (`/`), something  (`/something`) and a default page.

It works and now I would like to complicate a bit the logic. I need this:

```
/name=john&country=us -> Homepage
/something?name=john&country=us -> Something
```

So the same pages but adding two query params: `name` and `country`. These quesy params are not mandatory. If user goes to `/`, it should see Homepage as well.

I read the svelte-navigator documentation and I try this:

```
<main>
  <Router primary={false}>
    <Route path={'/*'}>
      <Route path="/">
        <Homepage />
      </Route>
      <Route path=":name">
        <Homepage />
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path={'/something'}>
      Something
    </Route>
    <Route>
      <h3>Default</h3>
    </Route>
  </Router>
</main>
```

`Homepage` component is something like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { Link, useLocation, useParams } from 'svelte-navigator'

  const location = useLocation()
  const params = useParams()

  $: console.log('location: ', $location)
  $: console.log('params: ', $params)
</script>

<main>
  <h1>Homepage</h1>
</main>
```

but it doesn't work as I expected because `http://localhost:8080/?name=john` visualizes `App` component.
How can I do what I need?

Note: I'm not using SvelteKit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have an issue with one of your declared goals:

```
/name=john&country=us -> Homepage
```

is not a valid URL, I am assuming this is a typo and you meant:

```
/?name=john&country=us -> Homepage
```

The mechanism to access query parameters using `svelte-navigator` seems a bit peculiar. With your stated goal of wanting to access the same query parameters across different routes, one approach is to use the `useLocation` facility provided by the library in an independent, top-level component, with the `name` and `country` values bound as properties:

```
// App.svelte
<script>
    import { Router, Route, Link } from "svelte-navigator";
    import Homepage from "./Homepage.svelte";
    import QueryStrings from "./QueryStrings.svelte";
    
    let name, country;
    
    $: console.log(name, country)
</script>

<main>
  <Router primary={false}>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/?name=joe&country=us">Homepage</Link>
        <Link to="/something?name=hans&country=de">Something</Link>
        <Link to="/test">Default</Link>
      </nav>
      <QueryStrings bind:name={name} bind:country={country} />
    </header>
    <Route path={'/'}>
      <Homepage />
    </Route>
    <Route path={'/something'}>
      Something
    </Route>
    <Route>
      <h3>Default</h3>
    </Route>
  </Router>
</main>
```

```
// QueryStrings.svelte
<script>
  import { useLocation } from "svelte-navigator";

  const location = useLocation();
    
  export let name, country;
    
  let qs;
  
  $: {
    qs = $location.search;
    getParamsFromQs(qs);
  }
    
  function getParamsFromQs(qs) {
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(qs);
    const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
    name = params.name || '';
    country = params.country || '';
  }
</script>

{#if qs}
<p>
    Raw querystring: {qs}
</p>
{/if}
{#if name}
<p>
    Name: {name}    
</p>
{/if}
{#if country}
<p>
    Country: {country}  
</p>
{/if}
```

This way, the `name` and `country` values are set at the top level (if they exist in the querystring, they're unset otherwise), and can then be passed on to child components/routes (e.g. `Homepage`) if needed.

[Here is a functioning REPL demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/d74eb6f8265b4fe2ab621d873050f9ae?version=3.49.0).

There are other similar approaches:

- using a combination of derived stores and/or context to store name & country and make them available (either globally or on demand), as suggested by H.B. in the comments
- wrapping your App inside a Router, then making use of `useLocation` directly at the App level (without the use of the extra component)
- using `let:location` in Routes wrapping child components where you want to access query parameters, then passing the location explicitly (in case you want to handle parameters on a component-per-component basis)

##### Update: quick outline of solution #2 above (wrapped App)

```js
// main.js
import WrappedApp from "./WrappedApp.svelte";

const app = new WrappedApp({
    target: document.getElementById("root"),
});

export default app;
```

```html
// WrappedApp.svelte
<script>
  import { Router } from "svelte-navigator";
  import App "./App.svelte";
</script>

<main>
  <Router primary={false}>
    <App />
  </Router>
</main>
```

```html
// App.svelte

// Because App is a child of Router, you can make use of useLocation

<script>
  import { Route, Link, useLocation } from "svelte-navigator";
  import Homepage from "./Homepage.svelte";

  const location = useLocation();
    
  let qs, name, country;
  
  $: qs = $location.search;
  $: getParamsFromQs(qs);
  $: console.log(name, country)
    
  function getParamsFromQs(qs) {
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(qs);
    const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
    name = params.name || '';
    country = params.country || '';
  }
</script>

<header>
  <nav>
    <Link to="/?name=joe&country=us">Homepage</Link>
    <Link to="/something?name=hans&country=de">Something</Link>
    <Link to="/test">Default</Link>
  </nav>
</header>
<Route path={'/'}>
  <Homepage />
</Route>
<Route path={'/something'}>
  Something
</Route>
<Route>
  <h3>Default</h3>
</Route>
{#if qs}
<p>
    Raw querystring: {qs}
</p>
{/if}
{#if name}
<p>
    Name: {name}    
</p>
{/if}
{#if country}
<p>
    Country: {country}  
</p>
{/if}
```

Comment: Alternatively one could define two `derived` stores that get the params from `location`, then either export/import them directly or pass them down the hierarchy using a context.

Comment: @H.B. yes that's a good idea, thank you. Amended the answer to provide a brief description of alternative ways to tackle the problem.

Comment: @ThomasHennes @H.B. The second idea seems interesting because it would allow you not to have an extra component (`QueryStrings`), right?
But in what sense should I wrap App inside Router? In App I already have a Router..
Could you post a snippet of this second alternative too?

Comment: @whitecircle because if App is not wrapped by Router, you won't be able to import and use `useLocation` (it can only be used inside descendants of Router).

Comment: @whitecircle added code outline describing approach #2